# [Python]Array function called in other function

Tags: python, arrays

I've tried to create a function that generated 3 variables for my arrays so I can call it in any further function I will create.

The 1st code was:

```
details = open('a.txt').readlines()

for x in details:

    host   = x.split()[0]   

    user   = x.split()[1]

    passwd = x.split()[2]

    print host + " --> " + user + " --> " + passwd
```

So the output is:

python b.py

192.168.1.1 --> user --> password

192.168.1.2 --> user --> password

Now, if I create multiple functions I have to use the same code as many functions as I create right? Then I decided to create the function to load those details from a.txt

Now, this is what happens:

```
def load_data():

global details,host,user,passwd

details = open('a.txt').readlines()
host   = [x.split()[0] for x in details]
user   = [x.split()[1] for x in details]
passwd = [x.split()[2] for x in details]
```

Great, now let's call load_data in another function and execute the actual function:

```
def execute():

load_data()

print host
```

Output:

python b.py

['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2']

I don't understand why the foreach (as in PHP) is not working if I call it in another function and execute it?

The output must be:

192.168.1.1

192.168.1.2

Can please somebody help me? (I'm a beginner in Python, so please take it slow.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the `host`, `username`, and `password` fields in order to get each of their separate values. You are just printing out an array.

E.g

```
def execute():
    load_data()
    for i in host:
        print host
```

That would output each value in host on a new line.

If you want to have the exact same output as your original program, you could do something like this:

```
def execute:
    load_data()
    for i in range(len(host)):
        print str(host[i]) + "-->" + str(user[i]) + "-->" + str(passwd[i])
```

Keep in mind that this assumes that `host`, `user`, and `passwd` all have the same length.

Comment: I see, it works (print i) but with that for I must go for each variable, then the load_data function have no sense as long as I have to re-write same fors in each functions, right?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the code is pretty much doing what you want, but the output isn't in the format you expect it to be. Let's see:

```
host   = [x.split()[0] for x in details]
```

Host will be a list. host[0] will be details[0][0], host[1] will be details[1][0], and so on.

```
print host
```

This prints the 'host' variable. You see "['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2']" because host is a list and that's just the way that python prints lists.

To print all the hosts you must do:

```
for i in host:
        print i
```

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer. It just shows what the question does.

Comment: Then any function to load arrays have 0 VALUE since you must rewrite the same thing (almost the same) in any new function to process those arrays (that's my opinion) i'm right or not?

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say that it has 0 value, it depends on what you're trying to do. But yes, if you want to read all the elements in an array, you'd have to use a for loop.